# Content editors are not able to edit versions of different language Sitecore 7.1

Tags: content-editor, multilingual

Has anyone experienced that content editor is able to change only one language (Dutch in this example) but not the English? 
Both languages have more than 5 versions. The strange thing is, when you select the languages on the top right side, English is not even shown. 
The role for content editors is the custom one, since certain items had to be hidden.

Comment: Was any security added on the languages?

Answer (score 9):

Check that the users' Roles have access to the Languages they are attempting to edit. You can do this by opening the Access Viewer, selecting the role, and navigating to System/Languages. Don't just check the `Read` and `Write` settings, it's the `Language Read` and `Language Write` settings that control access to Items based on that language. If `Language Write` is set to deny, the user will not be able to edit any content in that language. To see those, you will have to click the `Columns` button and make sure that they are selected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Richard. I was looking into the language column but on the item itself instead of the language item.

Answer (score 4):

You can check access rights for the particular group for the Language on `sitecore/system/Languages` children.

[image: Access right for languages]

If you remove write access to any of the languages then editors won't be able to edit the language.